# How can I synchronize the events for a group of channels in Netty...?

Tags: java, netty

Is it possible to synchronize all the events happening for a group of channels in netty.I have tried to achieve this using `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor`, but not all events are `synchronized`. Could you please suggest any methods to `synchronize` all events for a group of channels.

Thank you

Comment: what you mean with synchronize events ? Can you give some more details ?

Comment: @Norman Maurer  Synchronize here I means that I need to process one event only after completing processing of other events happends before in a group of channels.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is called a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) in java.

Initialize with

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition cond  = lock.newCondition();
```

In all functions you use is you need to lock the lock first, and make sure that you can release it:

```
lock.lock();
try {
  // do you stuff...
} finally {
    lock.unlock();//interrupt or not, release lock
}
```

In all places where you want to wait you call

```
cond.await();
```

And when all conditions need to continue have been met you call

```
cond.signal();
```